# Captcha Value is not reading while form submission

Tags: php, forms

I came across a problem with PHP form submission. I'm not able to read the captcha filed value in form submission. Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <h2 class="centertitle">Contact Us</h2>
   <div id="message"></div>
   <form method="post" action="php/contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" class="form-control" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div id="captcha">
                <input type="text" name="verify" id="verify" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Captcha" />
                <img src="php/image.php" alt="well, this is out capcha image" class="captcha" />
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
              <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" id="submit" class="sbtn" /> 
          </div>
       </div>
   </form>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Js Validation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Form Validation
    $('#contactform').submit(function(){

      var action = $(this).attr('action');

      $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
      $('#message').hide();

      $('#submit')
        //.after('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

      $.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        subject: $('#subject').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
      },
        function(data){
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
          $('#message').slideDown('slow');
          $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
          $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
          if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

        }
      );

      });

      return false;

    });
});
```

**Contact.PHP**

```
<?php

  if(!$_POST) exit;

   // Email address verification, do not edit.
   function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have entered an invalid e-mail address. Please try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($verify) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please Verify CAPTCHA.</div>';
    exit();
}else if(trim($verify) === $_SESSION["security_number"]) {

    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


$address = "contact@sreejesh.in";


$e_subject = 'Form Submission.';


$e_body = "You have a new Form Submission." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "Name: $name,\rPhone: $phone,\rEmail: $email" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h4>Email Sent Successfully.</h4>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, for your interest We will contact you shortly.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

*For some reason I'm NOT getting value of  `$captcha`
It returns an error says***
Currently the form get submitted without validation.
For Captcha image I use this code -

Captcha Code(IMAGE.PHP)

```
<?php
session_start();    
$img=imagecreatefromjpeg("texture.jpg");    
$security_number = empty($_SESSION['security_number']) ? 'error' : $_SESSION['security_number'];
$image_text=$security_number;   

$red=rand(100,255); 
$green=rand(100,255);
$blue=rand(100,255);

$text_color=imagecolorallocate($img,255-$red,255-$green,255-$blue);

$text=imagettftext($img,16,rand(-10,10),rand(10,30),rand(25,35),$text_color,"fonts/courbd.ttf",$image_text);

header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
header("Content-Disposition:inline ; filename=secure.jpg"); 
imagejpeg($img);
?>
```

I'm a beginer in PHP & I'm sitting with this code for the last few hours. PLs help.

Here is a live URL  - http://aisther.com/projects/sri/

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$_SESSION['security_number']` is returning a value?

Comment: what you are doing completely defeats the purpose of a captcha, it should be `if($_POST'verify'] ===  $_SESSION["security_number"]) {` do not echo out your session variable to your form

Comment: The default form method is GET so none of your variables will be available in POST.

Comment: @cmorrissey  both are different pages. so how will I get value of $_SESSION["security_number"] in contact.php? sorry, If I'm understand it wrongly. I'm still learning PHP

Comment: @sri session variables are stored server side

Comment: also, as @cmorrissey answered, if you echo your security_number on a hidden input, it will make your captcha pointless

Comment: @cmorrissey Thnks. I didn't know that it is stored in server side. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cmorrissey Not sure what happend now the form get submitted with out captcha validation. - http://aisther.com/projects/sri/

Comment: @sri you need to post you complete code here (including your image.php), we won't be visiting your site as we can't see your backend code which makes going there pointless

Comment: @cmorrissey In the URL you can see the actual PHP code used. Evey back end code written is there. Any way I will try to add it here. Thanks

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I got the issue solved. I was not starting session_start();  in contact.php. Addiing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Do not echo your session variable is it being created by your `image.php` script and exposing it to the user makes the captcha pointless.

HTML

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
  <div id="captcha">
    <img src="php/image.php" alt="well, this is out capcha image" class="captcha" />
    <input type="text" name="verify" id="verify" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Captcha" />
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
 session_start();
 if($_POST'verify'] == $_SESSION["security_number"]) {
      echo 'captcha matched';
 } else {
      echo 'bad captcha';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $_POST to read the form data, the form tag needs to look like

```
<form action='contact.php' method='post'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's there in the actual code. It still doen't helped. I'm getting the value of $verify

Comment: If the code in your question is not the actual code, we cannot help you. We are looking at the code you typed in the question. You probably have a typo in the actual code that you are hiding from us.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved after adding session_start(); in contact.php

final code(contact.php)

```
 <?php

  session_start();

  *********************************************************

  $verify   = $_POST['verify'];
  $captcha = $_SESSION["security_number"];

  *********************************************************
  if(trim($verify) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please Verify CAPTCHA.</div>';
    exit();
  }else if(trim($verify) != trim($captcha)) {
    echo  '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
    exit();
  }

  *********************************************************

?>
```